# How to specify a data type while importing a spreadsheet from gsheets (Google Colab) - Zero missing

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I am importing a data frame from google drive , and I have two columns with numbers. The problem is that when the number ends with a zero, this 'zero' does not appear in my dataframe (this column is set as a object) - For example 20.180 in the original dataset becomes 2.018.

I have already tried to change the data type after importing the files, however I guess the problem is in the type of data that it gets while being imported(object). I know that when using pd.read_excel I can choose the data type of the columns. Is there any way to specify this when uploading files directly from google sheets/google drive?

I am using the code below to import the file

```
planilha_reg = gc.open('base_modelo_REG')
aba_reg = planilha_reg.sheet1
df_reg = pd.DataFrame(aba_reg.get_all_records())
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot imagine `when the number ends with a zero`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: For example 20.180 in the original dataset becomes 2.018